# Why are Olga and Helga in blue?

Tags: hey-arnold

In the *Hey Arnold!* episode [Olga Comes Home](https://heyarnold.fandom.com/wiki/Olga_Comes_Home), we see that Helga and Olga are depicted in blue in a scene towards the end of the episode. Why is that?

[image]